# Examples of virtual hosts in the Apache manuals

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, man, apache-virtualhost

I'm preparing my self for a Linux exam, and I keep forgetting the format of an apache virtual host. At the exam, I am allowed to use the man pages and any documentation from the server, but I'm not allowed to use Google.

Is there any man page or documentation that can be found on a CentOS server that provides an example of a virtual host?

Such us:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@linuxrocks.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/linuxrocks.org/public_html
ServerName www. linuxrocks.org
ServerAlias www. linuxrocks.org linuxrocks.org
ErrorLog /var/www/html/linuxrocks.org/error.log
LogFormat "%v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" myvhost
CustomLog /var/www/html/linuxrocks.org/access.log
myvhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for CentOS 7:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/httpd-{VERSION}/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

or for CentOS 8:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/httpd/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your answer!